# FPC Connector 12pin Top & Bottom Contact

Tags: power-supply, pcb, fpc

I'll use 12 lines FPC cable (0.5 pitch) under 2 layer (6 lines Top & 6 lines bottom) because I've limited route space where the cable needs to cross.

Do you know any type of connector that match this requirement?
*Top contact 6pin
*Bottom contact 6pin

- Output Solder 12 lines
  Thanks